# Py4JJava wrong columns error when calling PCA of pyspark.ml.feature

Tags: pyspark, pca, py4j

I am trying to visualize word2vec words using pyspark's PCA function, but I'm getting an unhelpful error message. Saying column features are of the wrong type, but they aren't. (Full message below)

### Background

> spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7
>
> Scala 2.12.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_191).
>
> 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.
>
> Ubuntu 16.04

### My Code

```
maxWordsVis = 15

Feat = np.load('Gab_ai_posts_W2Vmatrix.npy')  
words = np.load('Gab_ai_posts_WordList.npy')
# to rdd, avoid this with big matrices by reading them directly from hdfs
Feat = sc.parallelize(Feat) 
Feat = Feat.map(lambda vec: (Vectors.dense(vec),))
# to dataframe
dfFeat = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Feat,["features"])
```

$dfFeat.head()

> Row(features=DenseVector([-0.1282, 0.0699, -0.0891, -0.0437, -0.0915, -0.0557, 0.1432, -0.1564, 0.0058, -0.0603, 0.1383, -0.0359, -0.0306, -0.0415, -0.0191, 0.058, 0.0119, -0.0302, 0.0362, -0.0466, 0.0403, -0.1035, 0.0456, 0.0892, 0.0548, -0.0735, 0.1094, -0.0299, -0.0549, -0.1235, 0.0062, 0.1381, -0.0082, 0.085, -0.0083, -0.0346, -0.0226, -0.0084, -0.0463, -0.0448, 0.0285, -0.0013, 0.0343, -0.0056, 0.0756, -0.0068, 0.0562, 0.0638, 0.023, -0.0224, -0.0228, 0.0281, -0.0698, -0.0044, 0.0395, -0.021, 0.0228, 0.0666, 0.0362, 0.0116, -0.0088, 0.0949, 0.0265, -0.0293, -0.007, -0.0746, 0.0891, 0.0145, 0.0532, -0.0084, -0.0853, 0.0037, -0.055, -0.0706, -0.0296, 0.0321, 0.0495, -0.0776, -0.1339, -0.065, 0.0856, 0.0328, 0.0821, 0.036, -0.0179, -0.0006, -0.036, 0.0438, -0.0077, -0.0012, 0.0322, 0.0354, 0.0513, 0.0436, 0.0002, -0.0578, 0.1062, 0.019, 0.0346, -0.1261]))

```
numComponents = 3
pca = PCA(k = numComponents, inputCol = "features", outputCol = "pcaFeatures")
```

### Error Message

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o4583.fit. : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: 
Column features must be of type 
struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>> but was actually 
struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>.  
     at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No, I haven't yet